# Change color of lineplot depending on data

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to change the color of a lineplot depending on data values using `pyplot` ?
For example, a red line when data is negative and a black line when data is positive.

I tried to split the data into two sets and plot them separately but there may be a better way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would just make two datasets and setting the right masks.
By using that approach i wont have lines between different positive
parts.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

signal = 1.2*np.sin(np.linspace(0, 30, 2000))
pos_signal = signal.copy()
neg_signal = signal.copy()

pos_signal[pos_signal <= 0] = np.nan
neg_signal[neg_signal > 0] = np.nan

#plotting
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plt.plot(pos_signal, color='r')
plt.plot(neg_signal, color='b')
plt.savefig('pos_neg.png', dpi=200)
plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

Comment: I'm using this implementation and it seems to be working, so thanks. Also, I'm digging the nate silver style graphs. When I try to use .style.use it says the module doesn't have anything of that name - would you know what's going on there?

Comment: old matplotlib, just comment out the line.

Comment: Is "style" in the new matplotlib? I would love to be able to use this style

Comment: This works for fairly dense smooth data points. It did not work well for sparse line plot.

Answer (score 8):

You can conditionally plot data in your axes object, using a `where` like syntax (if you're used to something like Pandas).

```
ax.plot(x[f(x)>=0], f(x)[f(x)>=0], 'g')
ax.plot(x[f(x)<0],  f(x)[f(x)<0],  'r')
```

Technically, it's splitting and plotting your data in two sets, but it's fairly compact and nice.

Comment: Note that will plot lines between zero crossings.

Answer (score 5):

If you use a scatter plot you can give each point a different color:

```
x = range(1)
x = range(10)
y = [i - 5 for i in x]
c = [i < 0 for i in y]
plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, s=80)
```

[image]

Comment: What worked better for me is `c = [ 'r' if i < 0 else 'b' for i in y]`

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a clean solution on stackoverflow without vanishing line segments that cross the x-axis.

Following this approach to compute new x values at the crossing point and updating the point arrays

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')


x = [2, 5]
y = [5,-3]

x1, x2 = x
y1, y2 = y
xf = x1 + -y1 * (x2 - x1)/(y2 - y1)

xn = [2, xf, 5]
yn = [5, 0, -3]
```

we get a crossing line segment with two parts.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,6))

plt.plot(xn, yn, 'X:')
plt.show()
```

[image: two part line segment]

Vectorizing this approach can be done by finding the crossing line segments, computing the crossing points and updating both point arrays at the appropriate indices for the x-axis (needs to be sorted).

```
x = np.linspace(-np.pi*2, np.pi*2, 40)
y = np.cos(x)

x1, x2, y1, y2 = np.stack([x[:-1],  x[1:], y[:-1], y[1:]])[:,np.diff(y < 0)]
xf = x1 + -y1 * (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1)

i = np.searchsorted(x, xf)
x0 = np.insert(x, i, xf)
y0 = np.insert(y, i, 0)
```

Drawing the updated arrays as a line graph with masked arrays for non positive and non negative y-coordinates.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,6))
plt.plot(np.ma.masked_array(x0, mask=y0 < 0), np.ma.masked_array(y0, mask=y0 < 0), 'o:')
plt.plot(np.ma.masked_array(x0, mask=y0 > 0), np.ma.masked_array(y0, mask=y0 > 0), 'o:')
plt.show()
```

[image: example cos graph]

To draw the original data with colored lines

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,6))
plt.plot(np.ma.masked_array(x0, mask=y0 < 0), np.ma.masked_array(y0, mask=y0 < 0), 'g-')
plt.plot(np.ma.masked_array(x0, mask=y0 > 0), np.ma.masked_array(y0, mask=y0 > 0), 'r-')
plt.plot(np.ma.masked_array(x, mask=y < 0), np.ma.masked_array(y, mask=y < 0), 'g.')
plt.plot(np.ma.masked_array(x, mask=y > 0), np.ma.masked_array(y, mask=y > 0), 'r.')
plt.show()
```

[image: old data multicolor]