# Different color for line depending on corresponding values in Pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to show parts of a line chart in different colors depending on the values of a corresponding boolean array (in this case `annotation`). So far i've tried this:

```
plt.figure(4)
plt.title("Signal with annotated data")
plt.plot(resampledTime, modulusOfZeroNormalized, 'r-', )
walkIndex = annotation == True
plt.plot(resampledTime[~walkIndex], modulusOfZeroNormalized[~walkIndex], label='none', c='b')
plt.plot(resampledTime[walkIndex], modulusOfZeroNormalized[walkIndex], label='some', c='g')
plt.show()
```

But this one joins the two colors and the background color is also visible.

I came across the `BoundaryNorm` but I think it requires y-values.

Any ideas how to color the line differently in some regions?

[image: The image with different colors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using the following code, but i think it quite a 'rough' solution

```
plt.figure(4)
plt.title("Signal with annotated data")

walkIndex = annotation == True
positive = modulusOfZeroNormalized.copy()
negative = modulusOfZeroNormalized.copy()

positive[walkIndex] = np.nan
negative[~walkIndex] = np.nan
plt.plot(resampledTime, positive, label='signal', c='r')
plt.plot(resampledTime, negative, label='signal', c='g')
```

Similar to the solution in this post: 
[Pyplot - change color of line if data is less than zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345489/pyplot-change-color-of-line-if-data-is-less-than-zero?rq=1)

Comment: You could use `np.ma.masked` instead of `np.nan`, then `matplotlib` excludes it

Answer (score 5):

The following is a valid solution for your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

# construct some data
n = 30
x = np.arange(n+1)           # resampledTime
y = np.random.randn(n+1)     # modulusOfZeroNormalized
annotation = [True, False] * 15

# set up colors 
c = ['r' if a else 'g' for a in annotation]

# convert time series to line segments
lines = [((x0,y0), (x1,y1)) for x0, y0, x1, y1 in zip(x[:-1], y[:-1], x[1:], y[1:])]
colored_lines = LineCollection(lines, colors=c, linewidths=(2,))

# plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.add_collection(colored_lines)
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

[image: Colored lines]

And by the way, the line

```
walkIndex = annotation == True
```

is at least not necessary, since if you compare a boolean array to `True` the result will be the same. You would, therefore, just write:

```
positive[annotation]
```