# Red line when data is negative and green line when data is positive in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I wanted to have the data in this graph as red when y is below 0 and green when it is above 0:
[image: profit]

I'm trying this, but unsuccessfully:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(rc={"figure.figsize": (20, 10)})

df_positive = df[df["cum_profit"] > 0]["cum_profit"]
df_negative = df[df["cum_profit"] < 0]["cum_profit"]

plt.plot(df_positive, color='green')
plt.plot(df_negative, color='red')

plt.show()
```

[image: neigh]

My data looks like this:

```
+---+---------------------+------------+-----------+
|   |     placed_date     | cum_profit | cum_stake |
+---+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| 0 | 2017-07-14 16:06:38 | -25.0      |        25 |
| 1 | 2017-07-14 16:26:42 | -50.0      |        50 |
| 2 | 2017-07-14 16:54:53 | -75.0      |        75 |
| 3 | 2017-07-17 16:48:07 | -150.0     |       150 |
| 4 | 2017-07-17 18:52:22 | -200.0     |       200 |
| 5 | 2017-07-17 18:54:51 | 10.0       |       250 |
| 6 | 2017-07-17 18:59:19 | 190.0      |       300 |
| 7 | 2017-07-17 19:06:41 | 140.0      |       350 |
| 8 | 2017-07-17 19:42:42 | 90.0       |       400 |
| 9 | 2017-07-18 12:46:59 | 154.0      |       450 |
+---+---------------------+------------+-----------+
```

**Update**
Latest attempt:

```
#df["positive"] = np.where(df["cum_profit"] > 0, df["cum_profit"], None)
#df["negative"] = np.where(df["cum_profit"] < 0, df["cum_profit"], None)

df.cum_profit.where(df.cum_profit.ge(0), np.nan).plot(color='green')
df.cum_profit.where(df.cum_profit.lt(0), np.nan).plot(color='red')

#plt.plot(df["positive"] , color='green')
#plt.plot(df["negative"], color='red')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Does it help if you set the "unwanted" values to NAN and plot them like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345489/pyplot-change-color-of-line-if-data-is-less-than-zero

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are running into is that matplotlib will draw a line connecting each consecutive plotable point.  By slicing your data frame, you are still providing all plotable points, just with a spaced out index.

To get around this, you can include the non-plotable points in the plotting operation.  Instead of slicing, use `.where()` and with the fill values as `NaN`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(rc={"figure.figsize": (20, 10)})

np.random.seed(200)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.cumsum(np.random.rand(10000)-0.5), columns=['cum_profit'])
df.cum_profit.where(df.cum_profit.ge(0), np.nan).plot(color='green')
df.cum_profit.where(df.cum_profit.lt(0), np.nan).plot(color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying a similar, as you can see by the update, but it still didn't work.

Comment: I did, but it seems like there will always be a space because it's different data sets. So not possible really.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with a different set of data, but overall should be able to be easy to apply it to your data. Use np.masked_where() to split the data into two chunks then plot it. The t variable is defining the frame from 0.0 to 2.0 and the scale by 0.01.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)

s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

lower = 0


supper = np.ma.masked_where(s > lower, s)

slower = np.ma.masked_where(s < lower, s)

cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['green'])

cmap.set_bad(color='red') 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(t, slower, color='green')

ax.plot(t, supper, color='red')

plt.show()
```

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjanU.png)

Answer (score 0):

This [Postt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76270203/how-to-plot-dates-on-the-x-axis-after-splitting-the-splitting-the-graph-in-posit/76270247#76270247) solved the problem! Add rows and change the values to -0.0001 and +0.0001! See the dataframe for an example

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34401679)