# How to plot dates on the x-axis after splitting the splitting the graph in positve and negative?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a line plot which is red when negative and green when positive, as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236622/red-line-when-data-is-negative-and-green-line-when-data-is-positive-in-pandas). This is done by splitting the dataframe into positive and negative and plot them individually. This is done using the following code:

```
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

    new_df.Performance.where(new_df.Performance.ge(0), np.nan).plot(color='green')
    new_df.Performance.where(new_df.Performance.lt(0), np.nan).plot(color='red')

    plt.show()
```

This works fine, but I am unable to plot the dates on the x- axis. It will only plot numbers. How can I fix this?

Here is a simplified version of the dataframe:

```
Date            Performance
8/2/2022 0:00   -1.01
8/2/2022 20:00  -0.0001
8/2/2022 20:00  0.0001
8/3/2022 0:00   0.19
8/4/2022 0:00   2
8/6/2022 0:00   0.0001
8/7/2022 0:00   -0.0001
8/8/2022 0:00   -5
```

Here, the 'Date column is a datetime object.

I tried adding x = 'date' and multiple variation to the code, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that will work?

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
# Assuming 'Date' is the column containing the dates
new_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(new_df['Date'])  # Convert 'Date' column to datetime if it's not already

# Set 'Date' column as the index
new_df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

new_df.Performance.where(new_df.Performance >= 0, np.nan).plot(color='green')

new_df.Performance.where(new_df.Performance < 0, np.nan).plot(color='red')

plt.xlabel('Date') 
plt.ylabel('Performance')  
plt.title('Performance Plot') 
plt.legend(['Positive', 'Negative'])  

plt.show()
```

Comment: Solved it, thx!